# I have trouble understanding the following derivation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to derive $$\int_a^t{\frac{f(s)}{W(s)}(\phi_1(s)\phi_2(t)-\phi_2(s)\phi_1(t))} ds$$

and I thought this would be just equal to
$$\frac{f(s)}{W(s)}(\phi_1(t)\phi_2(t)-\phi_2(s)\phi_1(t))$$

(by F.T.C if suppse the indefinite integral is $F$, then derivative of $F(t)-F(a)$  is equal to $F'(t)$ )

But this doesn't seem to be true and apparently the correct answer is:
$$\frac{f(s)}{W(s)}(\phi_1(t)\phi_2(t)-\phi_2(t)\phi_1(t))ds + \int_a^t{\frac{f(s)}{W(s)}(\phi_1(s)\phi_2(t)-\phi_2(s)\phi_1(t))} ds$$

I was wondering why and how do we justify this?

Comment: Presumably you are differentiating with respect to the upper limit  $t$. Here $s$ is the dummy "variable of integration" so there can be no$s$ in the answer when you use the FTC. Moreover, your expression is more complicated because there is also a $t$ in the integrand. See Leibniz integral rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Also, your correct answer is not correct. Under the integral you should have derivatives in the $t$-dependent factors.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The "correct" answer isn't just wrong, it's nonsense. I still see $s$  and a $ds$ in the term outside the integral.

Comment: Yes, but that was already contained in your first comment. And why is that first term there at all, as it is obviously zero? As a step in a calculation one might write this, but not as reference solution.